# Quaternions, Axis Angles and Rotation Matrices. Which of these should I use for FP Camera?

Tags: java, camera, lwjgl, quaternion

After 2 weeks of reading many math formulas and such I know what is a Quaternion, an Axis Angles and Matrices. I have made my own math libary (Java) to use on my game (LWJGL). But I'm really confused about all this.

I want to have a 3D first person camera. The move (translation) is working fine but the rotation isnt working like I need. I need a camera to rotate arround world Axis and not about its own axis. But even using Quaternions, this doesnt work and no matter how much I read about Euler Angles, everybody says to me dont touch on it!

This is a little piece of code that i'm using to make the rotation:

```
    Quaternion qPitch = Quaternion.createFromAxis(cameraRotate.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Quaternion qYaw = Quaternion.createFromAxis(cameraRotate.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    this.multiplicate(qPitch.toMatrix4f().toArray());
    this.multiplicate(qYaw.toMatrix4f().toArray());
```

Where `this` is a Matrix4f view matrix and cameraRotate is a Vector3f that just handle the angles to rotate obtained from mouse move. So I think I'm doing everything right:

1. Translate the view Matrix
2. Rotate the Move Matrix

So, after reading all this, I just want to know: To obtain a correct first person camera rotate, I must need to use Quaternios to make the rotations, but how to rotate around world axis?

**EDIT:**

OK, i'm following **@Sean Middleditch** solution and this should be good, but I think i've missed something...here is the code:

```
public Matrix4f getView() {
    if (!viewChanged) return viewMatrix; 
    if (position == null) position = Vector3f.createEmpty();
    if (rotation == null) rotation = Vector3f.createEmpty();

    viewMatrix = Matrix4f.createIdentity();
    viewMatrix.rotate(rotation);

    Vector4f forward = Vector4f.multiplicate(viewMatrix, new Vector4f(0, 0, -1, 0));
    Vector4f up = Vector4f.multiplicate(viewMatrix, new Vector4f(0, 1, 0, 0));
    Vector4f right = Vector3f.cross(forward.toVector3f(), up.toVector3f()).toVector4f();

    viewMatrix = new Matrix4f(new float[]{
            right.x,                                        up.x,                                       -forward.x,                                     0,
            right.y,                                        up.y,                                       -forward.y,                                     0,
            right.z,                                        up.z,                                       -forward.z,                                     0,
            -Vector4f.dot(right, position.toVector4f()),    -Vector4f.dot(up, position.toVector4f()),   -Vector4f.dot(forward, position.toVector4f()),  1   
    });

    setViewChanged(false);
    return viewMatrix;
}
```

Everything seems to be right, but the "Camera" is rotating now over the origin axis...and I think the problem is because I didnt understand the following:

> construct a regular rotation matrix, and then multiply the standard
>   camera vectors by that matrix

Thanks for reading it.

Best regards,

Afonso Lage

Comment: `multiplicate` ?

Comment: Sorry? multiplicate = *...

Comment: I haven't seen that operation called multiplicate before; doesn't mean it's wrong, I've just never seen it.  Doesn't LWJGL just call it `mul` ?

Comment: Yes but i'm creating my own math library, and because this i've wanted to use multiplicate instead of mul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use quaternions here.  Whoever told you to avoid Euler angles for first-person cameras was not speaking from experience.

A possible choice, if you really want to avoid Euler angles, is to store explicit `view` (`forward`) and `right` vectors.  You can then modify your yaw by rotating both vectors around `(0,1,0)`.  I assume you have an implicit "always up" vector like this; most FPS games do.  You can modify pitch by rotating both vectors around the right vector, which is `cross(view,up)`.

It's easier still to just store the Euler angles, construct a regular rotation matrix, and then multiply the standard camera vectors by that matrix.

```
// if you don't store the vectors pre-calculated
rotation = rotate(yaw,pitch,row)
forward = rotation * vec4(0,0,-1,0)
up = rotation * vec4(0,1,0,0)
right = cross(forward, up)

// maybe the transpose for your matrix class, don't know
camera = mat44(
   right.x, right.y, right.z, -dot(right, pos),
   up.x, up.y, up.z, -dot(up, pos),
   -forward.x, -forward.y, -forward.z, -dot(forward, pos),
   0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Euler angles can cause some problems in some contexts, but not generally here.  Unless you're making a free-form space shooter, odds are that you will have constraints on the pitch (something like `(-pi/2,+pi/2)`) and will not allow free control of roll.  The problems with gimbal lock, which are made out to be a much larger problem than they really are, will not be an issue for you in this use case.

Take a look at [gluLookTo](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) for more information on constructing a camera matrix.

Comment: I'd also be suspect of that camera matrix example I gave.  I can never for the life of me remember exactly how it goes.  Swapping back and forth between LHS/row-major and RHS/column-major doesn't help, either.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this seems to be the right way to do it, but I think i'm missing something because now the Camera is rotating over the origin axis...I've updated my question with my current code based on your answer. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: just double check that math, work out the values of `forward`, `up`, and `right` and `viewMatrix` for some "easy" rotations like "90degree left" and make sure you get in the computer what you get on paper.  I wouldn't trust any math I provided, I am the king of screwing up basic formulas.